# GameObject prefab deleting itself on runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

// THERE IS NO DESTROY CODE //

C# script in unity.

This is my script for my Player, and I have dragged and dropped the Prefab, tested it (it worked), but suddenly after I deleted one line of code (another GetComponent) it suddenly started deleting itself. Please help!

```
{
    // drag n drop

    public Rigidbody rb;
    public GameObject beanPrefab;

    // bool

    public bool gameOver;

    //float

    private float verticalInput;
    private float horizontalInput;
    private float speed = 30.0f;
    private float leftBarrierX = -21.6f;
    private float rightBarrierX = -3.0f;
    private float topBarrierY = 12.0f;
    private float bottomBarrierY = -5.0f;

    void Start()
    {
        // variables

        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        beanPrefab = GetComponent<GameObject>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // game loop

        if (!gameOver)
        {
            PlayerMovement();
            Barriers();
            // shooting
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                Invoke("Shooting", 0.05f);
            }
        }

    }
    // functions    

    void Shooting()
    {
        Instantiate(beanPrefab, transform.position, beanPrefab.transform.rotation);
    }
}
```

This is about the main stuff. I do have all dependencies and such, and as explained before suddenly stopped working out of nowhere.

Essentially, I drag the Bean prefab in, and after I drag it in, during runtime it vanishes and I have to drag it in again.

Comment: you will need to include the destroy code ...

Comment: there is no destroy code my friend, did you read the title? I said it was getting destroyed on its own, not that there was destroy code. I would've included it, no?

Comment: well it wont destroy anything without destroy code ...  actually i take it back what do you think `beanPrefab = GetComponent<GameObject>();` is doing?

Comment: PS its not desstroying it.... but you are forgetting what you set

Comment: I'm pretty sure the GetComponent is the way I'm supposed to get the beanPrefab? In every tutorial related to this I've seen, he puts GetComponent<GameObject>(); and adds it in the Inspector later on. What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Also I haven't programmed the destroy enemy code yet, what I'm talking about is how the prefabs gets unassigned in the inspector after I begin runtime.

Comment: Well. No. No its not. If its a prefab you either find it in assets or you set it in the inspector. By getting a component youre getting whatever this is on.

Answer (score 1):

If you have assigned the value in the inspector already, you do not need a `GetComponent`.

Both of these do the same thing – `GetComponent` just lets you do it at runtime. What you are doing is assigning the prefab, then the game loads and it is looking for a `GameObject` component on the `GameObject` that is running that script.

Just remove the `GetComponent` line and it will stop doing it.